# Eliminate highlighting of rendered code in vimtex

Tags: plugin-vimtex

I am trying out vimtex and I think it is great but I am annoyed because the rendered code looks highlited or selected. I attach a picture that shows what I am talking about. At first I thouhgh it may be a terminal asociated thing but I get the same problem on various terminal emulators. How can I disable this? thanks
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This is `hl-Conceal`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks for the reply. So how do I use h-Conceal to disable the highlighting?

Comment: You can customize the highlight applied to concealed characters. I’m not 100% sure, so I’ll leave it for someone else, but I think you just want to set ctermbg to NONE. (`:help :hi`)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble trying things If I run :hi clear Conceal in a vim session I get the desired result. Nevertheless I would like to make this automatic. I tried adding hi clear Conceal to my vimrc but it doesn't work. Any idea why? thanks a lot

Comment: Not sure, but if you like that solution than I would suggest `augroup ConcealFix | autocmd! | autocmd ColorScheme * highlight clear Conceal | augroup END` (replace bars with newlines).  Try that, and I’ll add and answer if it works.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I added the text you suggest to my vimrc (with vertical lines replaced with newlines) and It doesn't work. Thanks for the attempt though